# How to write a junit test script?

Tags: java, shell, junit

I wrote a java code which is working but I have to write a Junit Test Script for it, but I do not have the experience yet. I tried several hours, but I can not understand how it works. So your help is very welcomed. Thanks in advance :) Do you have any tipps for me? :)

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 class MailBox extends Frame {

   private boolean request;
   private String message;
   TextField tf1;

 public MailBox() {

   Dimension screenDim = getToolkit().getScreenSize();
   Dimension frameDim = getPreferredSize(); 
   setLocation((screenDim.width-frameDim.width)/2,    (screenDim.heightframeDim.height)/2); addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

 public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

   dispose();
   System.exit(0);
  }
 }
  Panel myPanel = new Panel();
  myPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  Label label1 = new Label("Message: ");
  Button button1 = new Button("Send");
  button1.addActionListener(new button1AL());
  tf1 = new TextField("", 20);
  myPanel.add(label1);
  myPanel.add(tf1);
  myPanel.add(button1);
  add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  setTitle("Mailbox");
  pack();
  show();
}

 public synchronized void storeMessage(String message){
   while(request==true){
    try{
      wait();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
    }
   }
  request = true;
  this.message = message;
  notify();
}
public synchronized String retrieveMessage(){

  while(request==false){
    try{
      wait();
    }
  catch(InterruptedException e){
    }
  }
  request=false;
  notify();
  return message;
 }

public static void main(String args[]) {

 System.out.println("Starting Mailbox...");
  MailBox MyMailBox = new MailBox();
  Consumer c1 = new Consumer(MyMailBox);
   Thread t1 = new Thread(c1);
   t1.start();
}

 class button1AL implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
  storeMessage(tf1.getText());
  tf1.setText("");
 }
}
}
```

Comment: My tip would be to indent your code properly, both for the benefit of yourself and others when reading the code.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that in your case the program did not reach yet the level when it should be Unit tested. I don't see any reason why you need to test that some constructor works when it just initializes the fields of the class and also that the program prints something. I would not check that.

In the case when you get some error and this error might contain different error messages, it is a good idea to verify that the message is the same, but this is not your case. So, the main point is that your unit test should test **business logic**.

Consider this template:

```
@Test
public void testGoUntilTankIsEmpty() throws Exception {
   // SETUP SUT
   Car car = new Car();
   car.fillFullTank();
   car.setSpeed(80);
   // EXERCISE
   int distanceInKm = car.goUntilTankIsEmpty();   
   // VERIFY
   Assert.assertEquals(800, distanceInKm);
}
```

In this case we exercise (test) specified method and expect that the result will be 800 based on our preliminary setup. If it is true your unit test will pass otherwise it will fail.

And remember that unit test should test only some unit, so some small piece of code, but actual functionality.

Answer (score 1):

JUnit's work by testing the code you have written with either the expected output, or incorrect output if you want to test whether your error handling works.

In your case you'd just test against the expected string it outputs.

So a basic test for what you have would look something along the lines of...

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
public class BasicTest{
      @Test
      public void describeAnimalTest(){
            AnimalNew animal = new AnimalNew("Dog", 10, "x"); 
            assertEquals("Dog is on level 10 und is a type of x", animal.describeAnimal(); 
       }
  }
```